# Make post archives with pure PHP and yii?

Tags: php, yii, archive

I would need to create archives listing ( much the same functionality as the ones in WP websites ), but with using PHP and Yii framework. Since i've been thinking about how I could accomplish this a lot and didn't come up with anything useful, i'm asking your help here.
So for example, mysql table would look something like this:
Columns:
id (int AI, primary )
title ( varchar )
content ( text )
creation_date ( timestamp )

How could I use the timestamp column value, to select only the posts in distinct months posted ( so that I can determine which months I need to list as links to the respective archive page which will list all the posts posted under that month ) ?

Btw, only helping me on how to do it with PHP is enough, you don't have to go through the hussle of making the code work with Yii since, obviously it is not possible, because you dont have controllers, models etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Gj to whoever voted down my question, you were realy helpful. I guess haters exist even on these kinds of websites, which is sad. Anyways ,enough about them, here is something I came up with today by learning new MySQL function, which I didn't know existed before :)
You can just use MySQL `DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%format')` to select the desired month, year, day, or any other "part" of the date, even though if the date is in unix timestamp. This is a simple code I came up with after a bit of fiddling around.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%M') as creation_month, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y') as creation_year FROM posts";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $archiveArray[] = $row;
    } 
    print_r($archiveArray);

    echo '<h3>Our Archives by month</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';?>

    <?php foreach($archiveArray as $archiveRecord) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href=""><?php echo $archiveRecord['creation_month'] . ' ' . $archiveRecord['creation_year']; ?></a>      
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; 
    echo '</ul>';

}
```

What this code does is it "reads" the timestamp in the "creation_date" column from the DB, puts it inside the desired "format" which is specified by %M and %Y ( similar to PHP date() function formating) and assigned to immaginary column names on the fly called craetion_month and creation_year. Note the DISTINCT select, since I don't want months to repeat themselves for each post under that particular month. After that we just list them as anchors in an unordered list. This was the main problem, the rest is easy to do :)